# How to include javascript generated text into html link?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript that displays a generated text into a div:
    document.getElementById('phrase').innerHTML = phrase;
    PHRASE_TEXT_GETS_SHOWN_HERE

Basically I'm trying to set up a link that will take the text and post it to twitter with a link:
    [Clicky for tweety](http://twitter.com/home?status=MY_TEXT_SHOULD_GO_HERE)

How can I include the generated text in the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like:

```
function setPhrase(phrase) {
  var url = 'http://twitter.com/home?status=' + encode(phrase);
  $('#phrase').html('<a href="' + url + '">' + phrase + '</a>');
}
```

...?

Un-jQuerying it should be straightforward enough, if that's how you roll.

This is un-jQueried:

```
function setPhrase(phrase) {
  var url = 'http://twitter.com/home?status=' + encodeURI(phrase);
  document.getElementById('phrase').innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '">' + phrase + '</a>';
}
```

If you didn't see my failbraining `encode` for `encodeURI` as an error you should use Firebug. It may also fail if you have more than one element with the id `phrase` or if you have no elements with the id `phrase`.

Comment: That's what I meant. I'll have a go at de jQuerying it but might be back if I get stuck - thanks!

Comment: Sorry... I'm completely lost here. I tried adding jQuery as I couldn't get it to work any other way, but the addition of jQuery didn't work for me.

Comment: That's got it! Thanks for your time (& patience!).